# Enable only backspace on onkeyevent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply need javascript to automatically add a celsius degree sign after the user starts typing into a text box.

I already have this code which is working as intended. It is adding the degree sign after the text:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var temp1 = new Value();
$("#Temperature1").on('keyup',function(e){
 
 var oldstr=$("#Temperature1").val();
 var tokens = oldstr.split('℃');
    var suffix = tokens.pop() + '℃';
    var prefix = tokens.join('');
 $("#Temperature1").val(prefix+suffix);
 
     });
});
```

```html
<input type="textbox" id="Temperature1">
```

The issue: Once the user starts typing in this field, the "℃" appears correctly, after the text. However, once the user has typed something, it can't be removed. User might change their mind and not want to enter something in the Temperature field. How do I only enable backspace?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may use `event.keyCode`. Guess for backspace, keycode is 8. [REFERRENCE](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

Comment: perhaps add and remove the sign on `blur` and `focus` to save needing to worry about real time adjustment of its position

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So instead of "$("#Temperature1").on('keyup' " I will use "$("#Temperature1").event('keycode' " ?

Comment: @haxxxton that is a nice solution but the issue is that once the user has finished a from, a copy is sent in PDF format to them with tables and such. So even if I hide it, it won't be hidden on the PDF form once they type in the field and can't remove the 'C'

Comment: so you could check if the field was blank and then not append the *C if there's no value in it.. assuming you wouldnt want just a number in the field with no *C appended?

Comment: what problem you are facing now with the code? I mean do you want that if a user presses backspace then it would delete digits from the backward?

Comment: @SajibBiswas yes that is exactly it. Since it's a "keyup" event, the "C" sign is still added even if the user uses backspace to delete.

Comment: basically this code must just enable the keycode "backspace", or "8" on keycode. I don't really know how I would implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var temp1 = new Value();

    $("#Temperature1").on('keyup', function (e) {

        if(e.which == 8) return; // added this line

        var oldstr = $("#Temperature1").val();      
        var tokens = oldstr.split('℃');
        var suffix = tokens.pop() + '℃';
        var prefix = tokens.join('');
        $("#Temperature1").val(prefix + suffix);

    });
});
```

I've added a line which checks if the pressed key was backspace. If YES, it returns from the function (i.e. not executing the rest of the codes of the function).

Comment: Thanks dude this worked! I just used if for the top condition and else for the bottom one :)